# Does New Relic real time monitoring assume a single user logged in to a web application?

Tags: testing, load, real-time, newrelic

I wanted to know if I get different results in New Relic real time user monitoring when many users are logged into the application concurrentky? Or the only way to achieve that is to use a load testing tool?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely see different results when more people are using your site at once.

The JavaScript injected for Real User Monitoring (RUM) collects timing information in the browser that contains details to identify the specific app and the web transaction processed on the backend, as well as how time was spent in the app for each request. When a page completes loading in an end user’s browser, RUM sends the information back to New Relic asynchronously, so it doesn’t affect page load time. RUM uses the IP address to resolve the geographic location of each request.

For more information on this see, [how real user monitoring works](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work), on the New Relic knowledge base.

Comment: I am running the pyramid project and integrated newrelic header/footer tags using custom tag by jinja2, here is the way i wrote custom template tags and running the pyramid app using NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program pserve developme
nt.ini --reload but still header/footer return empty by newrelic.agent.get_browser_timing_header() & newrelic.agent.get_browser_timing_footer(). I don't know what am i missing.