# writing jinja2 extension with pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2

I'm trying to write a custom jinja2 extension with Pyramid.

The extension code is:

```
from jinja2 import nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension


class SnippetExtension(Extension):

    tags = set(['snippet'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        print "Init"
        super(SnippetExtension, self).__init__(environment)

    def parse(self, parser):

        print "Parse"

        stream = parser.stream
        tag = stream.next()

        print "Writing"
        return nodes.Output('<div>Test</div>').set_lineno(tag.lineno)
```

I load the extension in `__init__.py` like this:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.include('pyramid_fanstatic')
    config.add_jinja2_renderer('.html')
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    add_jinja2_extension(config,SnippetExtension) #<--- load the extension
    config.scan()

    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

However I get the error:

> TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'snippet'

When parting the template:

```
{% snippet %}
```

What else do I need to do or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, Have you got your answer? Please help me if you have solve this, i am also facing the same.

Answer (score 3):

`add_jinja2_extension` is used for adding *file extensions*, not Jinja template extensions.

Template extensions should be listed in the [`jinja2.extensions` entry](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-jinja2/en/latest/#jinja2-extensions) instead.

You can pass those in with the `settings` mapping for example:

```
settings['jinja2.extensions'] = [SnippetExtension]
config = Configurator(settings=settings)
```

Comment: @CrazyGeek: and adding a full path (dot notation) to your configuration?

Comment: Please have a look at http://pythonfiddle.com/writing-jinja-extension-with-pyramid

Comment: @CrazyGeek: Why the underscore in `jinja2_extensions`?

Comment: Ohh, Thanks now it is not giving the error again, Let me test its working flow with new relic and i will be back to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help as it resolve the tag rendering issue but i am getting empty data from newrelic so would you please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746678/does-new-relic-real-time-monitoring-assume-a-single-user-logged-in-to-a-web-appl .

Comment: @CrazyGeek: I have very little experience with that tool, sorry.

Comment: FTR: the problem in the linked code is using `'jinja2_extensions'` as settings key, where it should be `'jinja2.extensions'`.

Comment: @ÉricAraujo yes, which is what I already pointed out at the time. Note that this is now 5 years ago.